# Realm migration failure: "Migration required"

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, realm-migration

I'm adding new properties to a Model But some Realm errors makes me confusing.
The first thing I tried was to change the regDate property(NSString) to an NSDate type.

```
RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
config.schemaVersion = 2;

config.migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t oldSchemaVersion) {
    NSLog(@"========== Migration executed ==========");
    if (oldSchemaVersion < 2) {
        [migration enumerateObjects:Track.className block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
            newObject[@"regDate"] = [dateFormatter dateFromString:oldObject[@"regDate"]];
        }];
    }
};
[RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config];
[RLMRealm defaultRealm];
```

and I also changed `Track.h`.

`@property NSString *regDate;` became `@property NSDate *regDate;`

But I got runtime error like this

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException',
reason: 'Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'Track.regDate' has been changed from 'string' to 'date'.
```

The reason says **Migration is required**. However, the migration block have never been executed.

I thought there are no other choices but to create new property from old Object and accept this useless regDate property.

So I changed migrationBlock:

```
config.migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t oldSchemaVersion) {
    if (oldSchemaVersion < 2) {
        // Note: Even if you don't have to convert placeholder values,
        // you still have to provide at least an empty migration block
        // when your schema has changes to nullability of properties.
        [migration enumerateObjects:Track.className block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {
            NSLog(@"========== Migration executed ==========");
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
            newObject[@"n_regDate"] = [dateFormatter dateFromString:oldObject[@"n_regDate"]];
        }];
    }
};
```

and added `@property NSDate *n_regDate;`

The Error was:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'Track.n_regDate' has been added.
```

and the migration block did not work this time either.

I seems like I missed something. Docs and Errors are not helpful to grasp what is going on.

Comment: Is this piece of code called in AppDelegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` function? When do you receive the migration error, is it on the line `[RLMRealm defaultRealm];`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor First, Yes It is. Secondly, Yes again. Have you any idea?

Comment: Then the only other probable cause that comes to my mind is that you haven't updated the `schemaVersion`. Are you sure it shouldn't be 3 instead of 2?

Comment: I checked again, I'm sure `schemaVersion` is 2 and `oldSchemaVersion` is 1.

Comment: So the migration block is executed? Or how do you know `oldSchemaVersion` is 1?

Comment: @GlebA. No It's not. I guessed it with `[RLMRealm schemaVersionAtURL:defaultRealmURL encryptionKey:nil error:nil]`

Comment: The problem just solved. Realm update(3.1.1 -> 3.5.0) working. Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem by updating Realm 3.1.1 to 3.5.0

I don't know whether this is a bug. However, if anyone is using version 3.1.1, I recommend updating.